# How to build and sign transactions without SDKs?

Tags: stellar-sdk

Following on the keypair generation thread, I am working on SDKs for different languages and I would like to build, sign and submit transactions so my question is what are the steps to do so?

Let's start with an operation for account creation:

```
createAccount {address, balance}
```

What are the steps to generate the tx envelope that will be sent to the Horizon RPC endpoint? Any Stellar guides I've missed? Pointers highly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best thing to do is to look at one of the official libraries and use them as guide. I can give you an high-level overview of the steps required to implement the base library to interact with stellar.

First of all, you need a [XDR](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4506) serializer and deserializer. You probably also want to auto-generate the XDR object classes for you language using a tool like [xdrgen](https://github.com/stellar/xdrgen). This is not strictly necessary, for my Rust library I wrote everything by hand.

Then you want to familiarize with the XDR definitions in [`stellar-core`](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/tree/master/src/xdr), start walking backwards from the [`Transaction`](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/master/src/xdr/Stellar-transaction.x#L297) definition.

The first thing to serialize is the public key, since it's used everywhere. From there you can start working on more complex objects (Asset, Operation, etc.) until you have everything needed for transactions.

I recommend using the official libraries to generate test cases, you can call the `toXDR('base64')` method on almost every javascript object and you will get back the base64-encoded XDR object.

Good luck!

Comment: Great! This at least is a starting point. Thanks.